# Is there a feature to add some vertical space to the bottom or scroll below last line?

Tags: notepad++

Whenever I'm doing some coding in Notepad++ i need to add some lines at the bottom so if i scroll down, the code doesn't stop at the bottom at the window. The problem is that I sometimes forget to take out the lines :/.

I need to know if there's some kind of plugin or feature that I may have missed that adds some vertical space at the bottom without being actual lines.

Or I have it all wrong and i should just resize the window?

Comment: oh ok, please move to appropriate place, :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use the NPPExec notepad++ plugin, and you could pass commands out this way.  Perhaps call up Perl then, complete the necessary commands and save.  Notepad++ should auto-update the file, and hey presto you have/don't have the remaining lines on the end of the file.

NPPExec can also execute commands internal to Notepad++ via Scitilla.  List can be found here, fifth post down;

http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331753/topic/3533638

Hope this helps!

Comment: it was answered here, thanks for your help :D 

http://superuser.com/questions/55863/is-there-a-notepad-feature-to-add-some-vertical-space-to-the-bottom-or-scroll-b